# PHP tree level nested menu recursive function

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a set of data in tree level

For example this is my database record

[image]

I wish to display it like

[image]

and so on.

Of course above picture is manually key in by myself

```html
 <?php 
   require 'tree.php';
   
   $tree = array(
      
   'wwq' => array(
   
         'Project4' => array(
        'phase1',
     
    ),
        
         'Project23' => array(
        'phase23',
     
    ),
   
    'Test1' => array(
        'test1',
     
    ),
         'Projecttest' => array(
        'phasetest',
      'testtest',
    ) 
   
     
    ),
    
   
 );
 
 echo treeOut($tree);
?>
```

and my function is

```html
<?php
function treeOut($row_Recordset1){
 $markup = '';
 foreach ($row_Recordset1 as $branch => $twig){
  $markup .= '<li>' . ((is_array($twig)) ? $branch . treeOut($twig) : $twig). '</li>';

  }
 
 return '<ul>' . $markup . '</ul>';
 
 }
?>
```

So, my question is how I can make the array to for loop instead of I key in every data.

Thankss if anyone could help me!! If any question can ask me below comment.

Comment: _"my question is how I can make the array to for loop instead of I key in every data"_ I don't get it, What would change with a for loop? As far as I can see whether you'd be using a `for` or `foreach` loop you'd still have to enter the same data?

Comment: Ya, the above array is manually key in by myself, but i don't want do that. I wish to get the data from for loop. May I know where I get wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If it is about how you can prepare array in required format before passing it to `treeOut()` function then try adding these line before calling `treeOut()`:

```
$tree = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY companyName ASC, projectName ASC, phaseName ASC";
$result = mysql_query($connection, $sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tree[ $data['companyName'] ][ $data['projectName'] ][] = $data['phaseName'];
}

echo treeOut($tree);
```

Hope this is what you're looking for and will help.

Comment: Thanks for helping!!!

However it still come out this error msg Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: Change `mysqli_*` to `mysql_*` if you are using old mysql functions.

Comment: same problem, it's just changed to Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysql. Besides that, i had add a global but it is still does not working